# Positioning a flash object with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, flash

If browser is internet eplorer I want shift the flash object next to the right column with code `document.getElementById("flashobj").style.left = "260px";` But it wouldn't work. I couldn't understand the problem.

[Here is a demo. It may help](http://cruisear.com/demo/left)

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="flashobj">You need Flash player 10+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.</div>

    <div id="banner">
    </div>

     <form id="combination" action="index.php" method="get" name="combination" target="_self">
                    <div class="FixedHeightContainer">
                        <div class="TContent">
                            <input type="hidden" name="view" value="" />
                        </div> 
                    </div>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        navigator.sayswho= (function(){
            var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
            var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
            if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
            M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
            return M;
        })();

        var browser=navigator.sayswho;
        if(browser[0] == 'MSIE')
        {
            document.getElementById("flashobj").style.left = "260px";
        }




      swfobject.addLoadEvent( ytplayer_render_player );
      function ytplayer_render_player( )
      {
        var so = swfobject.embedSWF
        (
          'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?video_id=_vx1OVLX5Rc&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&version=3&rel=0&fs=1&playerapiid=ytplayer',
          'flashobj',
          600,
          400,
          '10',
          null,
          null,
          {
            allowScriptAccess: 'always',
            allowFullScreen: 'true'
          },
          {
            id: 'flashobj'
          }
        );
      }
```

Comment: #flashobj {
        left: 260px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

Comment: @falguni How can i detect browser type and set if condition with css?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure position relative (or absolute, or fixed) is set on the element you're trying to position.